# How do I go back to my previous position after onoremap yank?

Tags: vim

UPDATE: I found a temp solution or permanent....

```
function! QuoteCallBack(timer) abort
call winrestview(g:savePos4QuoteTextObj)
call timer_stop(a:timer)
endfunction
```

I have an operator function that yanks double quotes or single quotes, ciq works fine because I want to be inside the quotes but when I do yaq (yank a quote) I don't want to move to the place where the quote is at. Seems like an easy task to just get back to the previous cursor position after the yank? I have tried the following things:

1. Tried setting the cursor position with an TextYankPost.
2. Tried setting marks in the actual mapping, probably not allowed cause it's expecting a motion.
3. Tried restoring cursor position from the function with setpos(). Probably don't work cause it's inside of the function.

This does not work maybe cause it's inside the function.

```
let saveCur=getcurpos()
execute "normal! mz"
call setpos('.',saveCur)
 exe "normal! `z"
if a:operator == 'y' | call setpos('.',saveCur)  | endif
```

Not too sure if a call back function would work. Jumps wont work cause `exe "normal 12lv"` is not a jump. This is the function. I know it's probably overkill when I could have just done `exe normal! ?\%` but I learned a lot of vimscript from it. Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks

```
function! QuoteTextObject(whole) abort

let char=a:whole ? 'a' : 'i'
let regex= '\v("|' . "').{-}".'("|' . "')" 
let res=matchstrpos(strcharpart(getline('.'),col('.')-1),regex)
let backRes=matchstrpos(strcharpart(getline('.'),0),regex)
let [start,stop]=copy(res)->remove(1,2)
let [bstart,bstop]=copy(backRes)->remove(1,2)
let offset=stop-start-1
let boffset=bstop-bstart-1

"if nothing was found forward or backward return
if res == ['',-1,-1] && backRes == ['',-1,-1] |call feedkeys("\e")| return 0 | endif

"find match backwards
if res == ['',-1,-1]  
    echom 'no match found forward'
    execute "normal! 0"
    let start=bstart | let offset=boffset
endif

if char == 'a' | execute 'normal! '.start.'lv'.offset.'l' | return 0 |endif
let offset=  eval(offset-2) > 0 ? eval(offset-2).'l':''
let icmd='normal! '.eval(start+1).'lv'. offset
if char == 'i' | execute icmd | return 0 |endif

endfunction

onoremap <silent> <Plug>QuoteOperatorWhole :<C-U> call QuoteTextObject(1)<CR>
onoremap <silent> <Plug>QuoteOperatorInner :<C-U>call QuoteTextObject(0)<CR>
omap iq <Plug>QuoteOperatorInner
omap aq <Plug>QuoteOperatorWhole
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What took care of it was calling a call back with `timer_start()` with a 1ms delay to restore the cursor position. I couldn't find any more answers so I went with that.